# I am not able to create function on AWS RDS with my user

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

> Error Code: 1227 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER
>   privilege(s) for this operation

getting above error, there are three users visible on my SQL Yog community
mysq.sys@localhost 
rdsadmin@localhost
root@%  <--------------This is my user 
even though I manage to give privilleges for create option, still not able to create my function my function starts as below

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getval`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`vfinances-dev.cf88ibo44fqq.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com` FUNCTION `nextval`(`input_name` VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS BIGINT(20)
BEGIN
    DECLARE cur_val BIGINT(20);

    SELECT value INTO cur_val FROM data WHERE name = input_name;

    RETURN cur_val;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I supposed to be having privillges of create option, or is this another paid services need to subscribe ?

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`xxxxxx.hhhhhhhh.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com` FUNCTION ...
```

Your problem is in the `DEFINER` directive.

As you have already indicated, your account is not this...

```
`root`@`xxxxxx.hhhhhhhh.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com`
```

...it's this...

```
`root`@`%`
```

In MySQL, accounts are identified by the combination of username and host pattern... and you can't specify the `DEFINER` as someone other than yourself, unless you have the `SUPER` privilege, because that would be a wide-open privilege escalation exploit vector.

Remove the `DEFINER` from your statement, since it serves no purpose -- the definer is automatically set to the actual defining user when the `CREATE` statement is executed -- or set it correctly.

Comment: I tried with root@% as well, it dint worked for me yet

Comment: Error Code: 1418
This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
This is error when try with definer as root @ %

Comment: This error should be self-explanatory.  Set `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to `1` in the parameter group for the RDS instance or cluster.  This option is not "less safe" in RDS, because RDS does not support unsafe logging.

Comment: I have a function that I'm trying to create (moved from another MySQL db) in a development RDS MySQL 8.x db, which I set up myself (privileges are not an issue).  log_bin_trust_function_creators is set to 1, and I rebooted the db.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Wing what does "doesn't work" mean?  You're getting the same error?  Remove the `DEFINER` or run the query `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` to find what you should be using.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I'm still getting the 'You do not have the SUPER privilege' and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bi_trust_function_creators variable). With or without `DEFINER`. Please don't misunderstand, it's not that I haven't used a database before so that I don't know who I'm logged in as, even following AWS's recommendations, this isn't working. I'll have to check everything on the AWS console.